# Why when I input not integer, catch doesnt work

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

I want that exception to be catched but it output mistakes Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "rr"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
I've tried in catch to write NumberFormatException but also dont work
This  is the code:

```
input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Donnez une note"));
            String s;
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < prs.size(); i++) {
                    s = prs.get(i).toString();
                    if (s.contains(String.valueOf(input))) {
                        filterStudents.add(prs.get(i));
                    }

                }

                if (!filterStudents.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "C'est les etudiants qui ont note: " + input + "\n" + filterStudents);
                } else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Il n'y a pas des etudiants avec note " + input);
                filterStudents.clear();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An Error Occured!");

            }
```

Comment: Doesn't the line number in the stacktrace give you any clue?

Comment: Move parseInt inside the try

Comment: Your call to parseInt have to be in the try block, not outside.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [No attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: If you indent your code properly (or have the IDE do it), we can better see whether the call to `parseInt()` is inside or outside the `try`-`catch` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try this :)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I definitely call the code in the question an attempt. Please be kind to this new SO user.

Answer (score 3):

Your try block does not include the `Integer.parseInt` call - which throws the exception.